# How do operators operate in array declarations?

Tags: c++

Why does `int a[x,y]` convert into `a[y]`, since comma operator operates left to right? I would expect `a[(x,y)]`, since inner operation will finish first. But in the first one it is supposed to take the first argument.

I'm not planning to use the comma operator for array initialization, just asking why this happens.

I read it in a book, and I'm confused.

**Update:**

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
 i = a, b, c;            // stores a into i 
 i = (a, b, c);          // stores c into i
```

So as first line of code says in the array the first value must be assigned to the array. Note: I'm not actually planning to use this. I'm just asking. I'm learning C++ and I read in a book that in an array declaration a[y,x]; so it should be a[y], x; not a[x]. Why does the compiler do this?

Comment: Probably `a[x][y]` is what you want to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you please give some context or at least some more code?

Comment: I would certainly be interested why this was downvoted. Seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: `int a[x, y]` will not compile. Variable-length arrays are not legal C++ so you can only have a constant expression there. You probably meant `int a[10]; a[x, y];` or something similar.

Comment: No way. I hadnt notice the down vote. Im bad luck brian here.

Comment: @Jhonnytunes I've edited my answer to explain the Wikipedia quote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comma operator `,` is also known as the "forget" operator. It does the following:

1. Completely evaluate the left operand
2. Forget its value
3. Completely evaluate the right operand
4. Use value of right operand as value of entire operator expression.

So in your case, it behaves just as it should. `a[x, y]` first evaluates `x`, then discards its value, then uses the value of `y` as the value of the entire expression (the one in brackets).

**EDIT**

Regarding your edit with Wikipedia. Note that the precedence of `,` is less than that of `=`. In other words,

```
i = a, b, c;
```

is interpreted as

```
(i = a), b, c;
```

That's why `a` is copied into `i`. However, the result of the *entire expression* will still be `c`.

Comment: Ok but how do you explain this: i = a += 2, a + b; Since (=) and (+=) has the same level of precedence. Well = is on top of += and still += is called first.

Comment: @Jhonnytunes Assignments associate right-to-left. Your expression is parsed as `(i = (a += 2)), (a + b)`.

Comment: With your edit now I understand. This "(i = a), b, c;" makes me  think again because I think the = sign as a operator waiting for the comma operator to evaluate everything. Now its clear, thanks.

Comment: @Jhonnytunes just an extra FYI: the comma has the lowest precedence of all operators

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your compiler is assuming that you meant to add parentheses. In C++ there's a comma operator and a comma separator. The comma operator must itself and its operands be enclosed in parentheses. The int array constructor only expects one value, so I'm guessing that your compiler is trying to help you out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh(v=vs.80).aspx

EDIT: int a[x,y] is not valid; int a[(x,y)] is valid; his compiler is assuming he meant to add parentheses. In a more general context the comma operator doesn't require parentheses. In function calls and initializers parentheses are required to distinguish between using a comma operator and a comma separator.

Comment: The comma operator does **not**, on its own, require parentheses.

Comment: MSDN disagrees with you: "Where the comma is normally used as a separator (for example in actual arguments to functions or aggregate initializers), **the comma operator and its operands must be enclosed in parentheses**."

Comment: And IBM http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fco.htm

Comment: int a[x,y] is not valid; int a[(x,y)] is valid; his compiler is assuming he meant to add parentheses. If you mean, in a more general context, that the comma operator doesn't require parentheses then I agree. In function calls and initializers parentheses are required to distinguish between using a comma operator and a comma separator.

Comment: @mikemxm but this still doesn't fit OP's situation - "where comma is normally used as a separator" does not apply here since, as you point out, `int a[x, y]` is not valid.

Comment: @Fiktik yes it does. His book says that int a[x,y] => a[y]. He wants to know why. The reason is because the compiler determines that a[x,y] is invalid and infers that the user intended a[(x,y)] which evaluates to a[y]. The compiler that I have installed via Xcode commandline tools package does not make this inference, and I'm not really sure why his  book would print that unless to illustrate that it might yield a runtime error (though it sounds like the book is not doing that).

Comment: @Fiktik you're reading that quote as "if here a comma normally is a separator you must use parentheses if you intend the comma to instead be an operator." That's what _should_ happen. The compiler isn't acting as it strictly should; it's trying to do a compiler equivalent of a typo autocorrect. The broader distinction trying to be made is that parentheses are used to eliminate ambiguity between the comma separator and the comma operator. The compiler says "He can't use a comma separator here. He must have meant a comma operator; let me fix that for him."

Comment: @mikemxm ok, thats a pretty wild assumption since we don't know what compiler he's using. Furthermore even if the compiler did that _mental leap_ and understand the declaration _as if_ there were parentheses, that should still fail to compile: `int a[x];` is not valid C++ (as long as `x` is an integral variable). It would have to be a constexpr. Or a compiler extension _again_ :-)

Comment: @mikemxm Anyway I didn't want to dispute your answer, but merely the _MSDN disagrees..._ comment. In my oppinion MSDN doesn't disagree.

Comment: @Fiktik Fair enough :-). Part of why this question is a pain is we're not dealing with his code and his compiler; we're dealing with something written in his book. I don't think anyone is trying to argue that this code should work, only why the book would say that int a[x,y] would yield a[y]. Without more context I have to wonder what the heck is going on in this book. And, yeah, we'd have to be dealing with constants for even the parentheses explanation to make sense.